# How to debug AWS Amplify REST API with lambda layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-amplify

I created the most mundane API in amplify and want to debug it with browser dev tools like you would do with node --inspect.

Problem:
Amplify mock doesn't support lambda layers and the docs don't mention any way of local backend development. Is that correct? Can you not develop an amplify app offline and access it on localhost? Is publishing (waiting 5 minutes), running the request, checking the console logs -> fixing typo,logical error &c, the Amplify Way TM?

Furthermore in my app I use autodesk forge to store and convert 3d models, how can I send a file (form-data) to my function, what should I put in my event.json for it to work?

Edit: Am I suppose to start the API gateway locally with SAM, if so how? And how come that debugging isn't taken into account from the get go and SAM not preconfigured? Has it something to do with the fact that most people use GraphQL instead of a REST API?